# Cypress: Returning value in promise within custom command?

Tags: promise, cypress

So I am trying to use a custom command to reduce the need to write the same thing in multiple files. Specifically this is for logging in and setting a token via JWT.

Here is the current working code (borrowed from JWT login example from cypress examples):

```
let user;
before(function() {
  cy.request("POST", Cypress.env("auth_url"), {
    username: Cypress.env("auth_username"),
    password: Cypress.env("auth_password")
  })
    .its("body")
    .then(res => {
      user = res;
    });
});
beforeEach(function() {
  console.log(cy.get_auth_token)
  cy.visit("/", {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      // set the user object in local storage
      win.localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
    }
  });
});
```

So i tried to do something similar via:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("get_auth_token", () => {
    let user;
    cy.request("POST", Cypress.env("auth_url"), {
        username: Cypress.env("auth_username"),
        password: Cypress.env("auth_password")
      })
        .its("body")
        .then(res => {
          user = res;
        });
    return user;

})
```

However when I try to call it within my `beforeEach` function as `let user = cy.get_auth_token` I get errors about user being undefined. Am I doing something wrong with returning the value? Im not an expert at promises...but this feels like it should be working?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the return value, just make it a plain JS function, not a custom command. Cypress commands do not return usable values [***You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command***](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands are not like functions, the return value is not assignable to a local variable. Instead they 'yield' it to the next command in the chain, which can be a `then()`. Also, the value is a 'subject' which is a jquery-wrapped version of the return value.

In short, this should be how you use your custom command:

```js
beforeEach(function() {
  cy.get_auth_token().then($user => {
    console.log($user[0]);
    cy.visit("/", {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        // set the user object in local storage
        win.localStorage.setItem("token", $user[0].token);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Would I still stick with my original command function? Would I need to adjust it for this?

Comment: I think, in your custom command you will need to move the `return user` line up into the `.then(res => {...})` part, because getting a response from the POST is going to be a lot slower than the custom command, so user will be returned before it gets a value. I'll mock up something and add to the snippet above.

Comment: There's already a good example custom command [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/90a839f2f056d91d9acb5d0d27cc5bddecea3135/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on/cypress/integration/logging-in-single-sign-on-spec.js#L49) and usage [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/90a839f2f056d91d9acb5d0d27cc5bddecea3135/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on/cypress/integration/logging-in-single-sign-on-spec.js#L104).

Comment: Also note Gleb uses a local auth server to test against, and Auth0 warns that ***Performing tests against Auth0 APIs may lead to your account being rate limited***, so worth duplicating that as well.

Comment: I've looked at other posts regarding returning values with Promises. Using `then()` to resolve getting the value from the Promise. However, is there a way to get the return value from async Cypress functions with `async/await` approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code inside a Promise and resolve 'user'. Using [Cypress.Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises), it will wait until user is returned:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("get_auth_token", () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     cy.request("POST", Cypress.env("auth_url"), {
        username: Cypress.env("auth_username"),
        password: Cypress.env("auth_password")
      })
        .its("body")
        .then(user => {
          resolve(user);
      });        
  })

})
```